# PHP if larger than (condition) no working?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

First I have the table called `trade_field`

```
+-----------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| UID       | durabletime    | productionQTY    | timestamp    |
+-----------+----------------+------------------+--------------+
| 88        | 1234           | 6.00             |1444400000    |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I query mysql and assign like this:

```
$queryCopper = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trade_field WHERE uid = ".$uid." AND fid = ".$fid."");

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($queryCopper)) {
    $idCopper[] = $row['id'];
    $timenow = time();
    $durabletime = $row['durabletime'];
    $Copperpdt = $row['production'];
    $CopperQTY = number_format(($timenow - $row['timestamp']) / 60 * $Copperpdt);

    if ($CopperQTY > $durabletime || ($CopperQTY > 1000 && $durabletime < 1000)) {
        $CopperQTY = $durabletime;
    } elseif($CopperQTY > 1000 && $durabletime > 1000) {
        $CopperQTY = 1000;
    } elseif($CopperQTY < 1000 && $CopperQTY < $durabletime) {
        $CopperQTY = number_format(($timenow - $row['timestamp']) / 60 * $Copperpdt);
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    };

    $user_list_Copper[] = $row;
}
```

So now we set `timenow = 1444450000` so the `$CopperQTY = 5000`
(Because `number_format(($1444450000 - 1444400000) / 60 * 6.00);`)

The Geranal Condition is:

```
if $CopperQTY > $durabletime
    then $durabletime = $CopperQTY
```

after that,

```
if ($CopperQTY < 1000 && $CopperQTY > $durabletime)
    then $durabletime = $CopperQTY
```

after that,

```
if $durabletime > $CopperQTY
    then $CopperQTY = $CopperQTY
```

after that,

```
if ($durabletime > $CopperQTY && $CopperQTY > 1000)
    then $CopperQTY = 1000
```

but when I run the above code, the system shows that `$CopperQTY = 5000`.

Comment: In your first `if` statement -> `$durabletime == $CopperQTY;` should be -> `$durabletime = $CopperQTY;`

Comment: I edit to `$durabletime = $CopperQTY;`, but still show the 5000 to me?

Comment: in a if-elseif-else first condition(if or elseif) to match true will execute its block and the flow will exit the control structure. in your case ony first if will evaluate and the $CopperQTY will remain unchanged and $durabletime will also become 5000.

Answer (score 1):

Based off the conditionals you stated, your `if-else-if-else` statement should be as follows:

```
if ($CopperQTY > $durabletime) {

    $durabletime = $CopperQTY

} else if ($CopperQTY < 1000 && $CopperQTY > $durabletime) {

    $durabletime = $CopperQTY

} else if ($durabletime > $CopperQTY) {

    $CopperQTY = $CopperQTY

} else if ($durabletime > $CopperQTY && $CopperQTY > 1000) {

    $CopperQTY = 1000

} else {
    echo "Error";
}
```

Since `$CopperQTY = 5000` and `$durabletime = 1234` then `$durabletime` will equal `5000` and the `if` statement will break.